# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-4

Tags: android, kotlin, swagger, kotlin-coroutines

I have created an android app with kotlin, and I am using swagger to get all WS 
Among the ws, one for create a new user, but an error appear, I put it below 
I want to know what's the mean of this error and how can I correct it 
Here's my code :

```
val current = LocalDateTime.now()
                   val userFirstName = firstName.text.toString()
                   val userLastName = lastName.text.toString()
                   val userEmail = userEmail.text.toString()
                   val userPassword = password.text.toString()
                   val userMobileNumber = mobileNumber.text.toString()
                   //   println(current)
                   val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
                   val date = current.format(formatter)
                       fireBaseAuthentication.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPassword).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                           if (task.isSuccessful) {
                               fireBaseIdNewUser = fireBaseAuthentication.currentUser!!.uid
                               val user = UsersData(
                                       fireBaseID = fireBaseIdNewUser,
                                       firstName = userFirstName,
                                       lastName = userLastName,
                                       phone = userMobileNumber,
                                       email = userEmail,
                                       image = "",
                                       birthDay = date.toString(),
                                       lastLogin = date.toString(),
                                       registrationDate = date.toString(),
                                       isActive = true,
                                       allowComment = true
                               )
                               GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

                               val newUser = mobileApi.apiMobileUsersCreatePost(user)////////////
                                   Log.e("test","$newUser")
                                    }
                           } else {
                               task.exception
                               Utility(this@Register).showMessage("Error: ${task.exception?.message}")
                           }
```

Here's the error :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-4
    Process: com.app.home, PID: 23639
    io.swagger.client.infrastructure.ServerException: Server error
        at io.swagger.client.apis.MobileApi.apiMobileUsersCreatePost(MobileApi.kt:947)
        at com.app.homecraft.activity.user.register.Register$onCreate$1$1$1.invokeSuspend(Register.kt:90)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:233)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:594)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:60)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:742)
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ? If yes, please share the answer. I'm also facing the same issue.